# Keeping xterm terminal alive on crunchbang linux debian wheezy

Tags: bash, debian, terminal, xterm, timeout

I like to keep a number of terminals open at different locations on my development VM. For this I use `terminator` because I got a big screen and I can divide the terminals anyway I want.

But after some time these terminals close one after another. I don't use ssh so any keepalive options would not work.

Is there any place where I can configure the terminal so that it does not timeout or close?

I am using `GNU bash, version 4.2.37` as shell and `terminator` on 'xterm`

Comment: Are you using `xterm` or `terminator`? These are 2 different terminal emulators, you can't use one _on_ the other. In any case, `terminator` does not close automatically, I have terminator windows open for hours if not days in my session. Same goes for `xterm`, what you describe is very strange. You have probably set something up yourself to do this. What is the output of `echo $TMOUT`?

Comment: echo $TMOUT gives me xterm ...

Comment: I have a plain setup of CB on top debian net install nothing fancy and all standard setup, but I got some things set in bashrc, I am going to look through that...

Comment: Ok it think I found the culprit :-) export TMOUT=600 in .bashrc :/

Comment: Sorry I missread your question about `echo $TMOUT` I actually read `echo $TERM` cause I just skimmed over it but you are absolutely correct with your assumtion that TMOUT is the culprit. Thanks a lot for the time and help!!!

Comment: No worries, you're very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is not the default behavior. The only way I can think of this happening is if you have set the `TMOUT` variable to something. From `man bash`:

```
   TMOUT  If set to a value greater than zero, TMOUT  is  treated  as  the
          default timeout for the read builtin.  The select command termi‐
          nates if input does not arrive after TMOUT seconds when input is
          coming  from  a terminal.  In an interactive shell, the value is
          interpreted as the number of seconds to  wait  for  input  after
          issuing  the  primary prompt.  Bash terminates after waiting for
          that number of seconds if input does not arrive.
```

In other words, `bash` will exit automatically in `$TMOUT` seconds.

So, you need to search for the file where that variable is set and unset it. This is probably going to be in your `$HOME/.bashrc` file but to be on the safe side, run this command which will search *all* possible config files for `TMOUT`:

```
for f in  ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login \
         /etc/profile /etc/environment /etc/bash.bashrc; 
do 
  [ -e $f ] && grep -H TMOUT $f; 
done
```

That should return a line like

```
/home/terdon/.bashrc:TMOUT=600
```

Delete that line from the relevant file and you're set.

Comment: Sorry I missread your question about `echo $TMOUT` I actually read `echo $TERM` cause I just skimmed over it but you are absolutely correct with your assumtion that TMOUT is the culprit. Thanks a lot for the time and help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are disconnected somewhere in the infra.

Open an extra xterm window, and enter

```
while [ 1 ]; do   /usr/ucb/echo -n .; sleep 40; done
```

You will get a dot every 40 seconds and enter ^C when you're finished.

Comment: yeah while this would work, it is very hacky. I found the issue though, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Debian has no /usr/ucb?

Comment: @Alex: You are right, the /bin/echo will do. You just need an echo that doesn't add a newline somehow, with the option -c or with ".\c". echo is not the most portable solution for this, I should have chosen for something like awk. I thought that `printf "."` was only supported by ksh (not bash), but on Debian it is!